# Помогите разобраться с Queue в `asyncio` Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Есть вот такой пример запускающий корутины по мере высвобождения слотов стека. Все работает так как нужно, но...  Не могу понять как этот реализовать с использованием `asyncio.Queue`. Ну тоесть хочу понять на этом примере как вообще работают `asyncio.Queue` но как в стенку...

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

limit = 3

start_t = datetime.now()


async def cor(sleep_time: float):
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(sleep_time, datetime.now() - start_t)


items = [10, 15, 4, 5]

tasks = set()

global_task_iterator = (asyncio.create_task(cor(item)) for item in items)


def top_up_tasks():
    while len(tasks) < limit:
        try:
            tasks.add(next(global_task_iterator))
        except StopIteration:
            break


async def start():
    top_up_tasks()
    while tasks:
        done, _ = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for done_task in done:
            tasks.discard(done_task)
        top_up_tasks()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())

# 4 0:00:04.006700
# 5 0:00:09.015482
# 10 0:00:10.005626
# 15 0:00:15.012813
```

Comment: не вижу тут Queue

Comment: И я не вижу ...

Comment: оно тут не нужно) в этом примере будет работать только как барьер

Comment: @eri, просто я эти Queue (слово то какое язык поломаешь нафиг) и так крутил и эдак, но не могу въехать как оно работает, думал может на этом примере получится разобраться. ((( Для того, чтобы написать в вопрос пример с использованием сабжа нужно хотябы в теории представлять откуда у него растут ноги и за какую сторону хвататься, а копипастить примеры из учебников как-то не "комильфо"

Comment: Кю нужны для выравнивания нагрузки при передачи с интерфейса с переменной скоростью или блокирующий на интерфейс с равномерной загрузкой. Допустим с одной стороны у тебя охранная сигнализация и нужно записать все события в базу. Сервер принимает событие, обрабатывает его, кладет в очередь и сразу готов к обработке следующего. Из другого таска это событие вытаскивается из очереди и пишется в базу. Без очередей сервер может также обрабатывать без задержки, если заменить аваит на таск.

Comment: @eri, Спасибо за разъяснения. Стало понятней, пожалуй вот с этой точки попробую на них глянуть. Видимо я не верно понимал область их применения

Comment: я в Queue пихаю входные данные для равномерной нагрузки